# Coin change: get the combinations recursively, how to save them to an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, combinations

Here's my code so far. I would like to resursively find all combinations which produce the given money sum. This is the test program which should print the combos, but as I excpected, there's an error

*ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0*

at two rows. Please help, I don't get it.
And how I save them to an array instead of printing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinChange {
public static void printCombos(int sum, int sumSoFar, int[] coinsSoFar) {

int[] coins = {5, 10, 20, 50};


if (sum == sumSoFar) {
System.out.print(coinsSoFar);
    }

else if (sum > sumSoFar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   
    sumSoFar = sumSoFar + coins[i];
    coinsSoFar[coinsSoFar.length] = coins[i];  // error row
    printCombos(sum, sumSoFar, coinsSoFar);
    
    }   
    
    }
    }

public static void main (String[]args) {

Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = read.nextInt();
int[] empty = {}; 
printCombos(sum, 0, empty); //error row
```

}
}

Comment: I think there is a problem with your algo. You are increasing sumSoFar and coinsSoFar in a loop, so given your example if the sum is bigger than the first coin you will never find a solution not using the first coin. And if you correct that problem you will find duplicate solutions...

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays don't automatically grow when you try to assign at an index beyond the length of the array. Thus the following will always give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (well, either that or a `NullPointerException` :)):

```
coinsSoFar[coinsSoFar.length] = ...;
```

The easiest option is to perhaps use an [`ArrayList<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for `coinsSoFar`, resizing it appropriately as you go along.